# Logic tests were running but now no longer, but Xcode says there were run successfully

Tags: xcode

I've got several logic test files which I've been successfully running, then in the last 1/2 hour I created a new header/source from the test template and added a new test case.

But now non of my tests are executing at all - if I put break points in them the aren't hit (this is any and all tests, including the ones that just a few minutes ago were running). I added an STAssertTrue(NO) line to confirm they're not running and they're not.

Yet XCode first flashes up a message saying its running the tests, and then a message appears saying Finished testing.

Why would it suddenly stop working, why is XCode lying and saying the test have run when then haven't? Why does it think they have run but they haven't?

I can see that the test files are still all present in the compile sources for the test target.

Xcode version = 4.2.1

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I observed the same behavior with XCode Version 4.3.2 (4E2002). I created logic tests that used files from main target (AppName). But these tests are never ran. I spent quite a bit of time poking around various stuff with no progress. I finally looked at [Apple's sample unit test project](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneUnitTests/Introduction/Intro.html) to figure out how they set up logic tests. The logic tests test files from the library target, not the application target. The model was encapsulated into a library which was then linked with the main target and logic tests target. The application target contained only views and controllers. This sounds like a reasonable separation to me.

Based on this model, this is what I did to get my logic tests work correctly. Create a new target (Cocoa Touch Static Library) and move all files to be logic tested (typically all your models) to this new target. Under **"Build Phases"** settings add this new library in **"Link Binary With Libraries"** of your application target and logic tests target.

I can imagine that these instructions are little confusing. If you dissect the sample project that is mentioned above you will get a better idea.